# Find the maximum possible dimension of $W:={\rm Span}\{v_1,\dots,v_{16}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be a real vector space and $v_1,\dots,v_{16}\in V$. Assume that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^8a_{2i-1}v_{2i-1}=0$ has infinitely many solutions and $\sum\limits_{i=1}^8a_{2i}v_{2i}=0$ has a unique solution. Find the maximum possible dimension of $W:={\rm Span}\{v_1,\dots,v_{16}\}$.

$1$st equation is linearly dependent so the $\dim$ would be at most $7$ and for the second equation $\dim$ would be $8$ since LI. This is what may I think. It's hard feeling that $\max\{\dim W\}=15$. But I don't know the proper way.

Comment: Thanks for adding the equations, but you should really enter them as text using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pasting a picture of them. Your question should be comprehensible to people who use screen readers, which can’t read images.

Comment: That aside, your reasoning seems OK to me. If you’ve got a linearly-dependent set of eight vectors, then at most seven of them can be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the maximum POSSIBLE is $min(\dim V,15)$ since you can indeed pick them all independently, and the min would be 8, since you don't know the rank of the first family of vectors.